# Build XML Off of Common Table Expression

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I am using a CTE to recurse data I have stored in a recursive table.  The trouble is I am trying to figure out how I can use "FOR XML" to build the desired xml output.  I have a Table of Contents table I am recursing and I want to be able to use that data to generate the XML.

Here is an example of what the data is simliar to:

```
ID|TOC_ID|TOC_SECTION|TOC_DESCRIPTON|PARENT_ID
1|I|Chapter|My Test Chapter|-1
2|A|Section|My Test Section|1
3|1|SubSection|My SubSection|2
```

I want to be able to spit out the data like so:

XML Attributes:
ID = Appended values from the TOC_ID field
value = value from TOC_Section field

```
<FilterData>
  <Filter id="I" value="Chapter">
    <Description>My Test Chapter</Description>
      <Filter id="I_A" value="Section">
        <Description>My Test Section</Description>
          <Filter id="I_A_1" value="SubSection">
            <Description>My Test SubSection</Description>
          </Filter>
      </Filter>
  </Filter>
</FilterData>
```

Not sure how I can take the CTE data and produce a similar format to the above.  When the data is in separate tables it isn't too difficult to build this type of output.

As always appreciate the input.

Thanks,

S

Comment: Is there a maximum depth to your data of 3 levels?

Comment: Hi Dave,

That is the problem...realistically I can't see it going over 3 or 4, but you never know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this out Will (Not sure you are still following)....this does have a 32 level max, but that should still work fine for my stuff...can't see going deeper than that.  Found this on another forum:

```
CREATE TABLE tree ( id INT, name VARCHAR(5), parent_id INT )

GO

INSERT INTO tree VALUES ( 1, 'N1', NULL )

INSERT INTO tree VALUES ( 3, 'N4', 1 )

INSERT INTO tree VALUES ( 4, 'N10', 3 )

INSERT INTO tree VALUES ( 5, 'N7', 3 )

GO



CREATE FUNCTION dbo.treeList(@parent_id int)

RETURNS XML

WITH RETURNS NULL ON NULL INPUT

BEGIN RETURN

(SELECT id as "@id", name as "@name",

CASE WHEN parent_id=@parent_id

THEN dbo.treeList(id)

END

FROM dbo.tree WHERE parent_id=@parent_id

FOR XML PATH('tree'), TYPE)

END

GO



SELECT id AS "@id", name AS "@name",

CASE WHEN id=1

THEN dbo.treeList(id)

END

FROM tree

WHERE id=1

FOR XML PATH('tree'), TYPE
```

Now isn't that nice and simple?

Customised from the great example over on http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345137.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You may get some mileage from [Recursive Hierarchies to XML](http://consultingblogs.emc.com/christianwade/archive/2006/09/20/SQL-Server-Standard-_2D00_-Recursive-Hierarchies-to-XML.aspx) in Christian Wade's blog - it all looks mighty painful to me!

Comment: You are right Will that is ugly.....I really want to avoid writing a CLR procedure...but I might have to.

Comment: I would try to do this transformation as far away from SQL Server as possible, personally, if you've an option to do this in code instead (in a client application) then I think you'll find that much simpler.